# Acronyms list indentation

Tags: lists, indentation, acronyms, description, acro

I'm writing a acronyms list using acro package and \printacronyms to print a list of acronyms, but some of my acronyms are a bit long and their are getting over the description, so I wanted to add a indentation on the description, how can I do it?. Thank you for your answers. 
Here is what's happening:[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{report}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{first-style=short}
\acsetup{list-heading=section*}
\acsetup{hyperref=true}
\acsetup{list-short-format={\bfseries}}
\acsetup{list-style=lof}

\DeclareAcronym{id}{
   short = \ensuremath{Entropia_{divisão}}, 
   long = Descrição da variável}

\begin{document}
    \printacronyms
    \vspace{2cm}
    \ac{id}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: Sorry for that, already changed it.

Comment: Easiest solution: Don't use `\acsetup{list-style=lof}`

Comment: yes but wanted to write the page number and could not find other styles that look like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to use `list-style=lof`, then you can change the width reserved for the short form using the `list-short-width` key:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{first-style=short}
\acsetup{list-heading=section*}
\acsetup{hyperref=true}
\acsetup{list-short-format={\bfseries}}
\acsetup{list-style=lof,list-short-width=3cm}

\DeclareAcronym{id}{
  short = Entropia\textsubscript{divisão}, 
  long = Descrição da variável}

\begin{document}
    \printacronyms
    \vspace{2cm}
    \ac{id}
\end{document}
```

[image]